# How to make toc ignore section formatting?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

In order to style my content, I try to color the section headings. I already have a default link color for toc. When I color my section heading, however, this format is carried to toc. I want toc to ignore that color because I color only few sections at the moment, and that section color is not suitable in toc. How do I achieve this?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{ISSUE: Section formatting in TOC}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Section 1}

asapgio pasigna psio  paiosngidpasng aoisngd apsignapgni agniaidapgip

\subsection{\textcolor{blue}{Section 2}}

asapgio pasigna psio  paiosngidpasng aoisngd apsignapgni agniaidapgip

\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Same example in overleaf:**  [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/vnhxbdkhxqvz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `\subsection` to specify a different title to be displayed in the toc:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{ISSUE: Section formatting in TOC}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Section 1}

asapgio pasigna psio  paiosngidpasng aoisngd apsignapgni agniaidapgip

\subsection[Section 2]{\textcolor{blue}{Section 2}}

asapgio pasigna psio  paiosngidpasng aoisngd apsignapgni agniaidapgip

\end{document}
```

Or (in my opinion preferable) use the colour instructions outside the `\subsection` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{ISSUE: Section formatting in TOC}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\subsection{Section 1}

asapgio pasigna psio  paiosngidpasng aoisngd apsignapgni agniaidapgip

{
\color{blue}
\subsection{Section 2}
}

asapgio pasigna psio  paiosngidpasng aoisngd apsignapgni agniaidapgip

\end{document}
```

Comment: @PaariVendhan You're welcome!